# Create custom grid in admin using ui component in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, grid-layout

I have done all necessary changes to create a grid in admin but I can not see the grid in my menu. I can see only title of a page in the menu but after that its showing blank.
Module — **Demo/Offers/**
Router name — **admin_offers**

> **/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Demo\Offers\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">demo_offers</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Demo\Offers\Model\ResourceModel\Offers</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="admin_offers_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Demo\Offers\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php

```
namespace Demo\Offers\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(Context $context,PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu("Demo_Offers::top");
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Manage All Offers')));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> view/adminhtml/layout/demo_offers_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="admin_offers_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/admin_offers_listing.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="context" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context</argument>
        <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Offer</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="admin_offers_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">offer_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">offer_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                        <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </columnsControls>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filters</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing.listing_top.bookmarks:current.columns.${ $.index }.visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterRange name="offer_id">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">offer_id</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                        <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterRange>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">offer_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="admin_offer/index/massDel"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="admin_offers_columns">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                     <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                 </item>
                 <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_columns.actions</item>
                         <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                         <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                             <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                             <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                         </item>
                     </item>
                     <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">admin_offers_listing.admin_offers_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                         <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                         <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                     </item>
                 </item>
             </item>
         </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="0">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">offer_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>

        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="offer_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="offer_title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Offer Title</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="offer_link">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Offer Link</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="offer_img">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">offer img</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="from_date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">from_date</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="to_date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">sate</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">to_date</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="active">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <!-- <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                     <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>-->
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status of offer</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Demo\Offers\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\OffersList">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">offer_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> Block/Adminhtml/Grid.php

```
<?php
namespace Demo_Offers\Block\Adminhtml;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container
{
    protected $_template = 'offers/lists.phtml';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_grid';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Demo_Offers';
        $this->_headerText = __('Posts');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Create New Post');

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

> Block/Adminhtml/Offers/Grid.php

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Offers\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Offers;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    protected $moduleManager;
    protected $_testFactory;
    protected $_status;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('offer_id');
        $this->setDefaultSort('offer_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setVarNameFilter('lists_filter');
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_testFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'offer_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'name'=>'offer_id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'offer_title',
            [
                'header' => __('Offer Title'),
                'index' => 'offer_title',
                'class' => 'offer_title',
                'name'=>'title'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'offer_link',
            [
                'header' => __('Offer Link'),
                'index' => 'offer_link',
                'name'=>'offer_link'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'offer_img',
            [
                'header' => __('Offer Image'),
                'index' => 'offer_img',
                'name'=>'offer_img'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'from_date',
            [
                'header' => __('Offer From'),
                'index' => 'from_date',
                'name'=>'from_date'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'to_date',
            [
                'header' => __('Offer Valid to'),
                'index' => 'to_date',
                'name'=>'to_date'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'active',
            [
                'header' => __('Offer Status'),
                'index' => 'active',
                'name'=>'active'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'edit',
            [
                'header' => __('Edit'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Edit'),
                        'url' => [
                            'base' => '*/*/edit'
                        ],
                        'field' => 'offer_id'
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
            ]
        );

        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="admin">
    <route frontName="admin_offers" id="admin_offer">
        <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Demo_Offers"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

Answer (score 0):

where is your admin route.xml file?

your layout file name is incorrect.

> view/adminhtml/layout/**demo_offers_index_index.xml** this should be **id(which specify in route.xml)_controller_action.xml**

Comment: I have route.xml but i have not given here. I changed name of layout file still its showing blank. is there any other changes in di.xml

Comment: please paste your adminhtml/route.xml in code  @MaNeo

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="admin_offers" id="admin_offer">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Demo_Offers"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>

Comment: so have you make file name admin_offer_index_index.xml and check after flushing cache? @MaNeo

Comment: you have to make Grid/Collection.php and resourceModel like Magento2 way.

Comment: Thank u rutvee I changed name of layout file and its showing grid now. I have already created collection but i thought the problem must be in di.xml of layout.xml files so that i have not posted the model data

Comment: okay @MaNeo  you can approve answer if it works for you!! so it will to others too in future!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I found so far.

1. Firstly as mentioned by Rutvee, you adminhtml/route.xml file is missing. 
   Where you have to make sure your id should be "demo_offers"
2. Secondly, Either go with purely UI component way or follow old way like you are trying to do in Grid.php.

Try to follow [this method](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html).

Notice How you are making columns in Grid.php is acceptable by M2 due to forward compatibilty in M1, but its not recommended at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can download from github for custom grid in admin using ui component and change accordingly as you want.

https://github.com/kirtinariya1/AdminGridUI

Answer (score 0):

I find it much easier to use the ["Ultimate Module Creator"](https://github.com/UltimateModuleCreator/umc) that creates the whole thing for you with a couple of clicks... it has some limits but it takes minutes for something that often done manually can take hours.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, it seems that you have set up the necessary files for creating a grid in the admin menu. However, there could be a few reasons why the grid is not displaying correctly. Here are a few things you can check:

1. Make sure the module is enabled: Verify that the module is enabled in your Magento installation by running the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   bin/magento module:status
   ```

   Look for your module in the list and make sure it is set to "Enabled."
2. Check for errors: Check your Magento logs for any errors related to your module. You can find the logs in the `var/log` directory of your Magento installation. Look for any relevant error messages that could help identify the issue.
3. Clear the cache: If you haven't already done so, clear the Magento cache by running the following command:

   ```
   bin/magento cache:clean
   ```
4. Verify XML configuration: Double-check your XML configuration files (`etc/di.xml`, `view/adminhtml/layout/demo_offers_index_index.xml`, and `view/adminhtml/ui_component/admin_offers_listing.xml`) for any syntax errors or typos. Make sure the paths and namespaces are correct.
5. Check file permissions: Ensure that the files and directories related to your module have the correct permissions and are accessible by the web server.
6. Verify the router name: Confirm that the router name specified in your module (`admin_offers`) matches the router name used in the URL when accessing the admin grid.
7. Verify the URL: Ensure that you are accessing the correct URL for your grid. Based on your code, it should be something like:

   ```
   http://yourdomain.com/admin/admin_offers/index/index
   ```

By checking these points, you should be able to identify any issues that might be preventing the grid from displaying in your admin menu.